# Cordova file download request canceled when content is PDF

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

In a Cordova + JQuery Mobile I upgraded from cordova@6.5.0, android platform@4.1.1 to cordova@7.1.0, android platform@6.5.0, the "direct" PDF download links:

```
<a href="..." target="_blank">...</a>
```

which worked well before the upgrade, stopped working.
The behaviour is peculiar: http request appears on chrome://inspect (network tab) as "pending" for a few moments, then as "canceled", 0 bytes transfered. 
On server side the request is regularly processed and answered with 200 OK, non-zero response size. This should exclude SCP issues I think.

Moreover the same method works for text files, images, ... NOT for PDFs.

Any suggestions?

**EDITs**

**Current SCP**

> "default-src * gap://ready; style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
>   script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * 'self'
>   data:"

**config.xml snippet**

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
```

Comment: post your security content policy

Comment: edited post including this info